# Reactjs: useEffect never triggered at first load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling with useEffect that's not triggered at app load, but is on a click on a button. here my code:

```
export default function Person() {

const [person, setPerson] = useState({});
const [hitRandomUser, setHitRandomUser] = useState(0);

const fetchData = setCallback(async () => {
   const api = "http://localhost/api/person/random";
   const response = await fetch(api);
   const data = await response.json();
   setPerson(data);
   console.log(data);
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();
 }, [hitRandomUser]);

const pax = {
   id: 1549,
   name: "Mikel",
   sexe: "boy",
   pop: 1
};
const onLike = () => {
    setHitRandomUser(hitRandomUser + 1);
    console.log(hitRandomUser);
    console.log("liked");
 };
 return (
      {!person.id && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
      <PersonCard person={person} onLike={onLike} />
  );
}
```

so this code is actually crashing my app. the problem is that useEffect is never triggered with make `person` an empty dict and then crashed at `PersonCard` when it tried to fetch `person.id`
However if I pass `pax` to `PersonCard`, everything works just fine. When I use the `onLike` function from `PersonCard`, then `hitRandomUser` state changes, and in that case `useEffect` is correctly triggered as it's a dependency.
How can I make useEffect triggers at load, or `setPerson` so I can use it to render?

## update

The issue i see is that if I use `pax` unstead of `person` to render my component like this:

```
return (
      <PersonCard person={pax} onLike={onLike} />
  );
```

I can see that the `useEffect` is actually rendered correctly because I can see the result of the `console.log(data)` with is displayed and correct. So there should be something firing an error, but I can't see it.

Comment: Hi Dany, a quick fix I would suggest would be to use an early return to avoid the component from being rendered until `person` has the value you are looking for. My assumption from what I understood from your message is that since the initial mount fails with an error, the hook callback is not firing. Familiarizing yourself with the React component lifecycle might be a good idea.

Comment: thanks @CristianHG what do you mean by 'early return'? I'm new to react

Comment: One of the things I like a lot about React is that it’s a very “natural” addition to JS. This means that most things that look like will happen a certain way usually will. You can simply choose to add a conditional, and inside of it, a return statement to stop execution. Quick example: `if (!person.id) { return; }` _(you could also return a static loading message in a div)_. This would go right above the last return statement in your component. As soon as `persona` updates React will automatically re-evaluate and re-render as needed.

Comment: got it, I've added something like at render `{!person.id && <h1>Loading...</h1>}` but same error. I also update the code and my answer

Comment: The objective of early return is to stop execution which isn’t happening in your updated example. This would need to be a **separate** return statement before the one that renders your `PersonCard` component. Read up on early returns: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/the-return-early-pattern-explained-with-javascript-examples/19364

Comment: thanks @CristianHG for your support, I fixed it by checking the sate of `person`, see answser

Comment: Please don’t update your question with working code, because then it loses context and relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `useEffect` is not running most likely due to the error that is happening during initial render. The Component lifecycle can give you some idea of what runs when and where.

I suggest using an early return statement (in our discussion  you used a standard conditional inside the JSX, which works as well, but I believe early return is a much better fit for this use case).

You can do something like placing this:

```js
if (!persona.id) {
  return <div>Loading…</div>;
}

// Other return goes here
```

Right **above** the return statement that renders `PersonCard`. This will stop execution and instead display the loading message until the precondition is met, in which case React will automatically re-evaluate and re-render the component.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this actually fixed my issue:

```
{!person.id && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
{person.id && <PersonSwitchCard person={person} onLike={onLike} onDislike={onDisLike} />}
```

thanks a lot @CristianHG

Comment:  no problem, see my latest comment if you’d like to learn more about early return. I strongly suggest it since this is the exact use case the pattern is designed for. If you are new to programming, using design patterns and conventions like these can save you a lot of headaches in the long run. 

Comment: I’m going to post a summary of our discussion as an answer if you don’t mind lol.